# How do you redirect the user to their previous page after logging in with PHP?

Tags: php

I have a log in widget included on every page on my website. Currently when they log in, they are redirected to the home page. However I want it so when they log in, they stay on the page they are currently viewing.

On my forum you have to be logged in to post (obviously). I would like it so they will stay on the forum post they are trying to reply to after logging in, rather than having to find it again. How do I do this?

Comment: It's probably a form submit, so you remove the action value.

Comment: It is, and it has no action value. EDIT sorry my mistake, it does have an action value which leads to a php page with all the login code on it. the widget i am including is pure html. Would it work if I moved all the php code to the same file and remove the action value?

Comment: It probably would, but just adding a `header('location: $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']')')` after the login would also do it.

Comment: OK it works now, but after I have logged in, it still shows the log in form. I have to refresh the page a second time for it to show me the profile stuff. EDIT I made a quick fix for it to refresh after a second if the user is logged in, but I don't want this to be the final solution

Comment: You shouldn't rely on referrer, it's more robust to know the current URL and use that to redirect after login.

Comment: @Jack I'm not using referrer. I just moved the PHP login code to the widget included on every page. There is just something silly going on with the if statements somewhere I think.

Comment: Without the code it's hard to tell you what it is.

Comment: I just realized what is going on. In my widgets include, i have an if statement that says if not logged in, show the login widget, else if logged in show the profile widget. since I made the login form's action blank, it will go back to itself first, even though the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest (albeit not completely reliable way is to use `HTTP_REFERER` and redirect to the referer page. You might need to pass this around a bit in case your login action spans multiple page.

The more proper way is to set the current (unlogged) page in session and redirect to that session value page on login.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the case but a couple options come to mind;

- Having a redirect parameter that will redirect the user once he logs in.
- Using the `HTTP_REFERER` to refer the user back to where he came from.
- Depending on the login form; you could send an ajax request to login the user without moving him

But I think it ultimately depends on your environment and since you haven't provided any information/code other than *my forum* I can only be as vague as your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind your current page inside your login widget inside a hidden field and tell the authentication page to redirect to this binded value as a page after login success .

Or if you want to be more secure try using `sessions` and bing the current page inside it then extract the variable binded into this session in your authentication page then redirect to it as a valid page

and you can also check this variable if is a valid page by using `file_exists` so plz try that and tell me the result